# omnipay pin payments with cake php 2.0

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0, omnipay

I need help regarding omnipay pin payments. i have no clue how to integrate this to cake php.

i tried this sample code but dint get success

```
$gateway = GatewayFactory::create('Pin');
$gateway->setSecretKey('your-secret-api-key');
$gateway->purchase([
  'email'       => 'customer@email.com',
  'description' => 'Widgets',
  'amount'      => '4999',
  'currency'    => 'USD',
  'card_token'  => 'card_nytGw7koRg23EEp9NTmz9w',
  'ip_address'  => '1.2.3.4'
])->send();
```

Fatal error: Class 'GatewayFactory'

Please help me . Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you including the Omnipay plugin in your code anywhere? You should have something like `use Omnipay\Common\GatewayFactory;`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [Composer](http://getcomposer.org/) to install Omnipay. This is explained in the [Omnipay Readme](https://github.com/omnipay/omnipay).

Make a file called `composer.json` in the root of your project directory:

```
{
    "require": {
        "omnipay/pin": "~2.0"
    }
}
```

Then run the following commands in a terminal window:

```
$ curl -s http://getcomposer.org/installer | php
$ php composer.phar update
```

This will download the Omnipay files into your `vendor/` directory.

Next, you will need to put the following line at the top of your `index.php` file, to register the composer autoloader:

```
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
```

Finally, you can use Omnipay in your project to create the Pin gateway:

```
$gateway = Omnipay\Omnipay::create('Stripe');
```

Comment: Better to use `require 'vendor' . DS . 'autoload.php';` as this is less dependent on the server being used.